# Deployment of Continuous Integration Infrastructure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, git, svn, continuous-integration

I want to implement CI for my project, but I've never done this before. Could anyone advice me on a great tutorial with step by step instructions on how to deploy a CI infrastructure?

Project: ASP.NET MVC based solution, source control could by either Subversion or Git

Comment: Do you have any preference as far as the CI server is concerned Jenkins, Cruise Control, etc.?

Comment: I have no any preferences, only one criteria, that Server should be free. Some says that free TeamCity is good enough

Comment: At a glance it does look good, Jenkins is another that seems to be growing in popularity in particular in the Java and Ruby communities.

Comment: TeamCity is annoying. Use CruiseControl.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another [good place to start](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a tutorial but this might be a good place to start: http://bencoffman.com/blog/2010/08/22/MakingContinuousIntegrationEasierCruiseControlCcnetCcnetconfigDefaultbuild.aspx